# How to split querySelectorAll results after filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm scraping some tables and filtering with querySelectorAll, but can't split the innerText results.

I've tried using `(.map(e => e.innerText).split("\t")[0];)`. It's getting me the first output, but I need to get the other rows of the array and assign their values to the variables.

My desired output is that I would like to `split("\t")` to assign each split to the variables: `Time`, `String2`, `String3`, `String4`, `String5`, `String6`.

```js
Actual Input:

 - '2020-07-17 12:30:00\tString2\tString3\tString4\tString5\tString6\t
 - \n' +

 - '\n' +

 - '2020-07-17 15:30:00\tString2\tString3\tString4\tString5\tString6\t  

 - \n' +

Expected Output:

$t_time = 2020-07-17 15:30:00
$S2 = String2;
$S3 = String3;
$S4 = String4;
$S5 = String5;
$S6 = String6;

 const result_table = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return [].concat.apply([], document.querySelectorAll('#app > div.page > div.content > table > tbody'))
  .filter(e => {
      const table = e.innerText;
      var t_time = table[0];
      var S2 = table[1];
      var S3 = table[2];
      var S4 = table[3];
      var S5 = table[4];
      var S6 = table[5];


      return (t_time, S2 , S3, S4, S5, S6);
  })
  .map(e => e.innerText).split("\t");

});
```

Comment: Where is your `split`?

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for here. As I understand it, this `result_table` string has the value at the top (`'2020-07-17 12:30:00\tString2...'`)? What do you want after that? Split that into an array (or array-of-arrays for each row)?

Comment: Thanks @nickf I've updated my question properly with what I'm trying.

Comment: Hey @James, I've updated my question.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with what you're trying to do. Can you simplify the post, all we need to know is `Input` and `Expected Output`.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Input: '2020-07-17 12:30:00\tString2\tString3\tString4\tString5\tString6\t
 - \n' + Output: Time = 2020-07-17 12:30:00, S2 = String2, S3 = String3, S4 = String4, S5 = String5, S6 = String6. It's clear now? Thank you

Comment: Input looks like an array of those strings.  Output should probably be an array of objects with named properties.

Comment: @James I know. But I can't split to put in the array. I'm looking for some answer telling me how to do.

Comment: Don't add the expected output to the comments section, add it to your answer.

Comment: @Konrad Pardon, but it looks like your input really is this tbody DOM element. Are you sure it wouldn't be easier to run through each row and each cell putting the inner text of the cell into the appropriate variable?

Comment: Hi @NateG I'm trying to figure out how to do. Appreciate any sugestion with the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry,  @Konrad that I'm on a deadline and don't have time to whip up a codepen for you, right now. I'm going to point you to documentation on `node.children` function of the DOM API. Basically, your `querySelectorAll` function will return an HTMLCollection of all tbody elements in the document. For each tbody, use children to traverse rows and then, again, cells (like looping through an array of arrays). Collect your innerText value on each cell and assign it variable. Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

Comment: Thanks @NateG I'll take a look